# Unit Test IActionResult with TempData

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I was just wondering how can you do unit testing with TempData without using MOQ or doing anything complex? Really appreciate your help

Here is my code:

```
public IActionResult ProjectsList(string selectedOrg)
    {

        TempData["model"] = selectedOrg;
        return View("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` is public property of controller, you can assert that expected key-value pair is in the bucket.

```
var controller = new MyController();
var expectedModel = "My organisation";

controller.ProjectsList(expectedModel); 

controller.TempData.Should().Contain("model", expectedModel);
```